# How can I search info and properties on a drive?

Tags: drive, file-properties, system-info

How can I easy find info and properties on a drive in the pc (or USB linked)?
Basically in windows you can use right click on the mouse and find the properties...

Comment: What information do you want exactly? Information regarding size and available space can be found in the same manner as in Windows.

Comment: When I click right mouse I am not able to see available space as in Windows

Answer (score 1):

If the drive was mounted,it will be shown on the devices list.Right-click on the particular drive and select properties.It will shows the used and free space available on that drive.

[image]